# java.lang.reflect.Type from canonical name

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to instantiate a java.lang.reflect.Type from its canonical name?

For example, create a Type from "java.util.List".

Thanks

Comment: If it's just a class, you can use `Class.forName`.

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman, but it's not just a class, as this canonical representation can be something like "java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>".

I've found a solution for this, I've added it to my initial question.

Comment: If you’ve found a solution, you should add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A class *is* a type and so does `java.lang.Class` implement `java.lang.reflect.Type`.

In other words, you can simply write

```
java.lang.reflect.Type listType=java.util.List.class;
```

or

```
java.lang.reflect.Type listType=Class.forName("java.util.List");
```

If the type is generic, a `Class` instance can stand for its raw type or the generic (parameterizable) type, depending on the context, e.g.

```
static void checkType(Class<?> type, Class<?> implemented) {
    if(!implemented.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
        System.out.println(type+" is not a subtype of "+implemented);
    }
    else if(implemented.isInterface()) {
        for(Type t: type.getGenericInterfaces()) {
            if(t==implemented) {
                System.out.println(type+" implements raw "+implemented);
            }
            else if(t instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                ParameterizedType pt=(ParameterizedType)t;
                if(pt.getRawType()==implemented) {
                    System.out.println(type+" implements "+implemented+" with");
                    TypeVariable<?>[] p = implemented.getTypeParameters();
                    Type[] actual = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
                    assert p.length==actual.length;
                    for(int i=0; i<actual.length; i++)
                        System.out.println("\t"+p[i]+" := "+actual[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
abstract class RawList implements List {}
checkType(RawList.class, List.class);
abstract class StringToIntMap implements Map<String,Integer> {}
checkType(StringToIntMap.class, Map.class);
```

prints

```
class Test$1RawList implements raw interface java.util.List
class Test$1StringToIntMap implements interface java.util.Map with
    K := class java.lang.String
    V := class java.lang.Integer
```